# @ManyToMany JPA relation using a 2nd degree relationship in join table and UK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have this entity model (simplified):

```
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  String id;

  Collection<B> bs;
}

@Entity
class B {
  @Id
  String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", nullable = false)
  C c;
}

@Entity
class C {
  @Id
  String id;
}
```

What would be the best approach to add a join table between A and B (many-to-many relation) and enforce a composite UK using A.id and B.c.id?

I tried something like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
        (name = "a_b",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                        @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "c_id")},
                uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uk_a_c", columnNames = {"a_id", "c_id"}))
```

but I get a `MultipleBagFetchException`, which is very strange. It must be related to the fact that `c_id` is not part of the primary key. If I remove `c_id` from `inverseJoinColumns` it works as expected, but it's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final mapping looks like this:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(ABListener.class)
@Table(name = "a_b", uniqueConstraints =
@UniqueConstraint(name = "uk_rel_a_b", columnNames = {"a_id", "c_id"}))
public class AB extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id")
    private C c;

    public AB(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    /* rest of the class */
}
```

And a listener to handle setting of `C`:

```
public class ABListener {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void handleCUpdate(AB ab) {
        if (ab.getB() != null) {
            ab.setC(ab.getB().getC());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If between B and C it's a one-to-one association, you could share the primary key between those two, so that

```
B.id = C.id = B.c.id
```

Then the join table unique key can be between A.id and B.id.

Comment: That was fast :) Thx. Sorry, but my question was incomplete. It's ManyToOne between B and C.

Comment: If it's a many-to-one than you'll duplicate the B-C relation, you could do it in the database using a pre-insert validation trigger. Anyway B is already associated to both A (as there's a one-to-many association from A to B) and to C (as there's a many-to-one association from B to C). So B is already a link table for A and C, hence the UK can be added in B as (a.id, c.id)

Comment: A-B is a many-to-many relation. I was thinking of using a JoinTable with both b.id and b.c_id as inverseJoinColumns, but because c_id is not part of the pk it doesn't seem to work (i get a MultipleBagFetchException)

Comment: The `MultipleBagFetchException` is thrown if we have to EAGER Lists or you try to JOIN FETCH two Lists. It works with Sets although you end-up with a Cartesian Product.

Comment: I know that's usually the problem, but all *ToMany relations are Lazy. If I leave only the pk in inverseJoinColumns I don't get the error anymore, so I think it's linked to having a non-pk column in inverseJoinColumns. But I didn't find any docs on this.

Comment: I don't know. I usually avoid exotic mappings like theses ones.

Comment: I finally went for a join entity and two one-to-many compositions. Thanks! Your answer and blog were both helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. You can either add the solution to this answer or post a new one with your solution.